# How do I add a div inside a THREE.js scene

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

Hi guys I want to add a div tag with some contents into a THREE.js scene is there a way I can do that. Lets say we had a cube in the scene that was created like
 var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,100,100);
I tried doing something like var geometry = document.getElementByID('div_tag') and later creating a mesh and adding the mesh to the scene like
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
It did not work is there a way I can do that? thank you

what I have:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<body>

<div id="mainDiv">   <!---this is what I want to add to the scene-->
    <div id="boxDiv">

    <div id="front"></div>
    <div id="back"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>


</div>
</div>
<script src="http://alt.graceland.edu/~gta1/three.js-master/three.js-master/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="cube.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

init();
        animate();

```
    function init(){
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 500;

        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
        controls.addEventListener('change', render);

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,100,100); /* instead of   this I  want the div tag */
        var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }

    function animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        controls.update();
    }

    function render(){
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
```

Comment: Put a working demo together

Comment: [link] http://alt.graceland.edu/~gta1/New%20folder%20(3)/cube.html

here you go.. I want to put the cube I created through CSS into my scene..
The reason for that is that.. I want to add links in my cube.. and through the 3d cube created through THREE.js, it seems hard.

Comment: Linked resource will eventually die and when they do this question will be of no use for future users, so the code needs to be within the question, clearly showing what you have tried yourself and what is not working

Comment: It looks like you want something like this: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/ Is that correct?